# center a paragraph in the middle of parent div regardless of parent divs size

Tags: jquery, css

I am having a real difficulty. I have a number of images with a caption on top of the image.

I am trying to center the caption horizontally and vertically regardless of the size of the image

I presume it would be  a little bit of clever Jquery but I can't seem to find anything out there.

Below is the url for the page

http://satbulsara.com/luke-irwin/?page_id=175

Thanks,

Sat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this solution

```
$('.wp-caption-text').each(function() {
this.style.position = 'absolute';
this.style.top = $(this).parent().height()/2 + 'px';
this.style.marginTop = -$(this).height()/2 + 'px';
this.style.left = ($(this).parent().width() - $(this).width())/2 + 'px';
```

});

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is to add a `left` and `width` property to contain the text. However, this does make the assumption that the text is limited in length.

```
#rugs #content .rugsAll div p {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 24px;
    left: 35%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 4;
    top: 40%;
    width: 20%;
}
```

If you have varying length captions. Then you will need jQuery to dynamically set the `left` and `top` property to center it based on the image size.

Comment: yeah thats what I thought, I will be having various length paragraphs so need jquery to set the left and right

Answer (score 0):

sat,
If you make the width of your `<p>` class 100% then the `text-align:center` will place your text in the center horizontally.

Vertical alignment is trickier.  You should probably wrap your `<p>` in a container and `vertical-align:middle` that container.

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

p .wp-caption-text {
     position: relative;
     display: block;
     z-index: 40;
     font-size: 24px;
     text-align: center;
     width: 100%;
     color: #fff;
```

}

**HTML**

```
 <div id="attachment_249" class="wp-caption alignnone" style="width: 319px">
      <img class="animal new" title="Rug-12" src="http://satbulsara.com/luke-irwin/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/Rug-121.jpg" alt="" width="309" height="453" />
      <div class="container">
          <p class="wp-caption-text">
          testing 8
          </p>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I believe something like this will work.  Play around with it, but I think it'll do.